# Insert or duplicate tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to achieve to update the data: I have products and quantity... I need the quantity to be apdated with old quantity plus new quantity in case if the product is already in database
Example: I had already 3 apples and I want to insert 2 apples more. The result should be productname=apple and quantity=5. Sorry for my poor English, hope it is clear my problem.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (productname, quantity) VALUES (’apple’, ‘2’)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ptoductname; // <-- not sure
```

please help!

Comment: You haven't specify any action on UPDATE...

Comment: is quantity a varchar or other string-y field? That's probably going to be a problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `quantity` is a numeric data type and `productname` is either the `PRIMARY KEY` or has a `UNIQUE KEY` constraint which would be violated, use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = quantity + 2`:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (productname, quantity) VALUES ('apple', 2)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = quantity + 2
```

Without a constraint enforcing uniqueness, the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause won't have any effect and you'll wind up with two rows.

Note: I have replaced the curly apostrophes `‘` with proper single quotes `'`.

Comment: You can also write it as `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = quantity + VALUES(quantity)`

Comment: Hi, actually I received two raws of Apple... one with 3 and other raw with Apple 2... but I would like to have only one Raw with Apple 5...

Comment: @SergiuCostas Is `productname` defined as a primary or unique key? If it isn't, then the `INSERT` statement could not fail with a duplicate key violation. You must define it as PK or place a unique index on it.

Comment: @SergiuCostas Then you must define a PK on `productname` or a `UNIQUE INDEX` to make this work. Otherwise you would have to query in application code to find out if the row exists then add to it or insert a new one.